# Can I add custom attributes to an option value in select(drop down)

Tags: html-select, html

Is this possible. I fill my drop down from different sources. I was thinking of separating different entries odf adding a custom attribute something like this:

```
<option value="12" customatrribute: "123" >NAME</option>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The attribute you are using is considered as invalid, if you want to make your own, you need to have [`data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) prefix as it is valid as per HTML5 specification.

From the specification:

> A custom `data` attribute is an attribute in no namespace whose name
>   starts with the string "`data-`", has at least one character after the
>   hyphen, is `XML-compatible`, and contains no characters in the range
>   U+0041 to U+005A (LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A to LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z).

So you can use something like

```
<option value="12" data-customatrribute="123" >NAME</option>
```

Also note that you need to use `=` and not `:`

---

As you commented, here's the screenshot of the source, it does show up for me
[image]

Comment: I've tried your answers but it does not seem to work. I dont get that attribute inside my elements. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jacob What do you mean by *I dont get that attribute inside my elements*

Comment: Later when I dynamically print my drop down options.It only contains the key:value pair and not the custom value...

Comment: @Jacob check out the image in my answer

Comment: I am creating everything dynamically and I am also using a dojo select widget

Comment: Yep. Dojo is the problem. Do you maybe know any hacks to make this work on a dojo select widget